# Swift Data(contentsOf) Arguement passed to Call that takes no Arguements

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, download

```
let url = URL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/w5rkSIj.jpg")
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)

if let imageData = data {
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
}
```

I am trying to do the above for loading an image from url but when i type the `Data(contentsOf: url)` line i get an error saying `"Argument passed to call that takes no argumens".` What may be causing this? `NSData(contentsOf: url`) works but i need the Data one

Comment: Are you sure that's the error you're getting? You _should_ be getting this error: `error: value of optional type 'URL?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'URL'`, because you have not unwrapped your `url` variable. (At least that's what I get when pasting this code into a playground.)

Comment: Yes, I am sure of the error, I'm thinking I'm missing some kind of import so I added `import foundation` but it didn't work, also I am running this in a UITableViewCell, .xib file, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Is there a custom struct `Data`?

Comment: No there is no custom struct data

Comment: Your `url` is an optional, and you need to unwrap it.

Answer (score 0):

url is optional variable so use optional binding

```
 guard let url = URL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/w5rkSIj.jpg") else {
        return
    }

    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)

    if let imageData = data {
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    }
```

Comment: The issue is not with the url, The Data function seems to not exist.

Comment: @KiddKidd What happens when you view definition of `Data`? I had to do `Foundation.Data`